# HTML + PHP how to prevent webpage from displaying anything until submit is pressed

Tags: php, html

I am new to both HTML and PHP and I encountered a problem when working on some simple projects. Lets say I have a text bar on my webpage and I want to display the text written in text bar on webpage after the user enters some text and presses the submit button. My problem is that the webpage shows the output when the webpage first loads. Is there a way to prevent the php code from executing untill the submit is pressed ?

Here is a sample code code that indicates the problem I am referring to.

```
<html>
    <body>

        <form action="./index.php" method="GET">
            First Name: <input type="text" name="first" maxlength="50"><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="GO"/>
        </form>


    </body>
</html>



<?php
    $text_var = $_GET[first];

        echo "This was typed into text bar" . $text_var;
?>
```

So "This was typed into text bar" is outputted right away when website loads.
I want it to be outputted only after submit button is pressed.

Thanks.

Comment: You should also replace `$_GET[first]` with `$_GET['first']` or `$_GET["first"]`. See [Why is $foo\[bar\] wrong?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar) and [Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) in the manual for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

you need to split it up the form should be showed if nothing is submited so either check the value or the submit button 
make sure you keep the html format. look at label tags to describe form inputs

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="./index.php" method="GET">
            <label for="first">First:</label>
            <input id="first" type="text" name="first" maxlength="50"><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="GO"/>
        </form>
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['first'])) {
  //take care you escape things never output user input (XSS)
  $op = htmlspecialchars($_GET['first']);
  echo "This was typed into text bar" . $op;
}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if `$_GET['first']` exists. This is is usually done as the following:

**View**

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <!-- input fields here -->
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO"/>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // process post
} else {
  // display the form
}
```

Comment: please check my answer about security dont echo user input

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $text_var = $_GET[first];

        echo "This was typed into text bar" . $text_var;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Please put some more effort in your answer.